# Access to new php files

Tags: .htaccess, https, url-rewriting, url-routing

I was helping a friend with a website and I created few php pages that he then copied to the root. The problem is that the htaccess file is setup in a way that I'm not able to access any of the new php files that I created but I can access all the html files. I looked into a lot of documentation for editing htaccess but I couldn't make it work. Any help is appreciated. The new pages that I have added are contact.php, show-captcha.php and thank-you.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [NC]

#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !71\.239\.5\.36
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/img(.*)$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sync/$
#RewriteRule $ /maintenance.html [R=302,L]

##Errors##
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php

##Redirect##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.net/$1 [R,L]

##Common Files##
RewriteRule ^(.*)\~\57(.*)$ $1Main.php?file=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)ajax\57(.*)$ $1Main.php?ajax&$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)sync\57(.*)$ $1Main.php?sync&$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)backup\57(.*)$ $1Main.php?backup&$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)SampleDoc(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57?)$ $1index.php?count=$3 [NC]

##REDIRECTS##
RewriteRule ^(.*)menu(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57)(.*[^\57])$ $1menu.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)menu(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57?)$ $1menu.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)menu(\57?)$ $1menu.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)checkout(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57)(.*[^\57])$ $1checkout.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)checkout(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57?)$ $1checkout.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)checkout(\57?)$ $1checkout.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)ThankYou(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57?)$ $1ThankYou.php?$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)ThankYou(\57?)$ $1ThankYou.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)Contact(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57?)$ $1contact.php?$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)Contact(\57?)$ $1contact.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)account(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57)(.*[^\57])$ $1account.php?type=$3&email=$5&code=$7 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)account(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57?)$ $1account.php?type=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)account(\57?)$ $1account.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)catering(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57)(.*[^\57])$ $1catering.php?$3$5 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)catering(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57?)$ $1catering.php?$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)catering(\57?)$ $1catering.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)changepassword\57(.*[^\57])\57(.*[^\57])$ $1account.php?type=changepssd&email=$2&code=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)join(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57)(.*[^\57])$ $1account.php?type=join&email=$5&code=$7 [NC]
```

I tried to add contact.php but you can see it's not helping.

Comment: How are you attempting to access the new php files? What's the URL you are using?

Comment: www.sample.net/contact.php and that page has file included like require_once("./include/fgcontactform.php");
require_once("./include/captcha-creator.php");
I have www.sample.net/menu.php working with the above file

Comment: I checked the inspector in  the browser and all it says is 500 Error

Comment: What's a working URL look like in this mess?

Comment: An actual url is http://therockrestaurant.net/menu.php
Im trying to make http://therockrestaurant.net/contact.php work

Comment: I don't understand how most of these rules even does anything. I don't think the problem is the rules themselves, are you sure it isn't something wrong with contact.php (or one of the files you are including)?

Comment: I have that exact same file on my personal server http://vinitvarghese.com/rock/contact.php

Comment: I'm sure the code works, but you're getting a 500 Server error, and if you're accessing the site via URL's like `http://therockrestaurant.net/menu.php`, these rewrite rules aren't doing anything. So somewhere something else is wrong. Maybe turn on php debugging or look through the error logs.

Comment: Thanks, I will check everything once again.

Comment: Or even perhaps, try removing all the rules under `##Common Files##` temporarily just to make sure they're not affecting the executing of contact.php

Comment: the issue is with these lines :

##Redirect##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.therockrestaurant.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://therockrestaurant.net/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://therockrestaurant.net/$1 [R,L]

Comment: Can you see the apache error log ?

Comment: @remi.gaubert: No, the whole site is maintained by another person and all he can give me is the .htaccess ....I created some similar folders and changed the site name etc on this htaccess and used it on my own server and the same problem occured....So i'm really sure that it's this file that is causing the problem..specially those few lines I posted right above your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the rewrite rules at all if you are not going to move path variables to the query string. Just remove the RewriteRules for the contact page. If you are still getting the not found page, remove

```
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
```

All errors, from Page Not Found to Server Errors are all getting the same error.php. There may be some error in your contact.php and that is why you always get this page.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I will give that a shot..Since only one hour is left on the bounty, I will award it to you...but I will get back to you after testing again..Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try to delete the existing lines with contact

```
#RewriteRule ^(.*)Contact(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57?)$ $1contact.php?$3 [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)Contact(\57?)$ $1contact.php [NC]
```

and add these:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)contact(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57)(.*[^\57])$ $1contact.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)contact(\57)(.*[^\57])(\57?)$ $1contact.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)contact(\57?)$ $1contact.php [NC]
```

And take care to be case-sensitive.